# Conditional compilation of a source file that must be included only in debug builds

Tags: c, makefile, macros, embedded, conditional-compilation

I have been reading best practices for conditional compilation, but I haven't found an example for the situation I have.

I have a C project whose target platform is a specific device (different from a PC). I have a source file that only contains functions for integration testing and things like that. I want this file to be compiled and linked only in `DEBUG` builds, not in the `RELEASE` ones.

**My question is which of the following options is a better practice:**

A`*.c` file like the following:

```
Tests.c
---------
#ifndef NDEBUG
// All testing functions
...
#endif
```

And include that file in both `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` builds.

**Or**

Checking whether or not `NDEBUG` is defined from within the  project's `Makefile / CMakeLists.txt` and including the mentioned source file consequently.

Comment: The professional (but unhelpful) answer is: you should not have any debug compiler switches in your application at all. Debug vs release is handled 100% by version control. In practice I use these switches too... but its a bad habit of mixing debug and release code, because it is so easy to slip and leave debug left-overs in the release, particularly during maintenance.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree. If you have two copies of the same thing, they will get out of sync, guaranteed. The best method is to use macros like `ASSERT()` which automatically doesn't compile debug code for release.

Comment: @shawnhcorey It's rather trivial to merge changes from the trunk into a debug branch through. For some systems it is a requirement that there exists no debug code in the production release. And in general, it is a pain to read code with tons of compiler switches in it. It's easy to say "just use assert", but most often you want something more intricate than a one-liner boolean test.

Comment: @Lundin Then write a macro for it. Don't forget that `ASSERT`s are also documentation.

Comment: @shawnhcorey My usual approach is to integrate an error handler into the program itself and then use that one for debugging. But if that's feasible depends on the nature of the application, of course. For almost all embedded systems, it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal opinion (!) on this:

**The first approach -- `#ifndef NDEBUG` -- is preferrable.**

In the beginning, there was `cc *.c`.

Then came the adding of appropriate options.

Then came build systems, which figured out which of those `*.c` files actually *needed* recompilation, and relieved you of remembering which the appropriate options *were*.

Then came more sophisticated build systems, which could figure out the appropriate options for you.

Over time, build systems have become smarter, and *can* hold significant logic. However, I feel that this intelligence should remain focused on their primary function (see above), and that -- in the end -- a `cc *.c` should still be doing its job.

Build systems get outdated, or replaced. The next guy might not even know your build system of choice; he should still be able to make heads and tails out of your project without having to dig through your build system's logic as well.

Setting / checking `NDEBUG` is C, and anyone with a passing familiarity of the language (and `<assert.h>`) will immediately recognize what you're intending to do there.

Figuring out why a specific source file should only be included in a specific build type but not in others, from your build system, is not so intuitive, and might get lost altogether when somebody steps up, tosses your `CMakeLists.txt` out because he likes Jam better and builds that from scratch. That person might end up wondering why all those tests are cluttering up his release code, and why you weren't smart enough to make them Debug-only (not realizing you *did* do that in your build system).

Comment: From my experience ultimately it all depends on project/codebase size. There is a size threshold when `#ifdef` switches start to become insufficient. Also, the argument that someone could remove buildfiles is not that convincing. Buildfiles should be under source control and for big projects build system is equally important as the source code itself. Using `ifdef`s alone requires a lot of discipline to avoid the [ifdef-hell](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/living-in-the-ifdef-hell/)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I don't understand why to choose only one? In my opinion, both options can and **should** be used together.

If some file is totally unnecessary in a release build, then you have the perfect reason to exclude it from the building process completely. But having some preprocessor guards in the source code (be it `#ifdef` or `#error`) is by all means very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first approach (`#ifndef NDEBUG`) is better, why?

Because I believe that each code encapsulation or dependency should be performed at the lowest level possible. If the build system can go on with its job without knowing that this file is compiled only for DEBUG builds, then we've just successfully removed a dependency in our project.

Building on top of the last argument, if this file will be needed by an additional project in the future, you'll have two places that behave conditionally instead of a single one.

Comment: The issue (in my opinion) is you've introduced a file that the compiler must build even when it doesn't need to.   It's not so big of a problem when you've got tens of files, but hundreds or thousands start making longer and longer builds.   Death by a thousand paper cuts, if you will.

Comment: @RussSchultz, well, if you have hundreds or thousands of source files that are `#ifdef`-ed out, I would guess you should extract some of your code into a shared resource, be it a library or something similar. I can't think of any legitimate scenario for that to happen...

Comment: exactly.  you do something in the build system to isolate that bundle of stuff so it gets included or not.  Which was my point.